# Issue updating a View on another instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server 2014 database that is basically a set of views to a 3rd party remote SQL Server instance that we connect to as a linked server. They are upgrading to 2016 and said that we would need a 2016 instance to connect to their system soon.

I setup a new instance on the same server we have SQL Server 2014 and created a new database there. In the 2014 instance, we have a snapshot of a few tables, which we refresh a few times each day. Pulling data from their system is working fine with this setup, but we have a couple spots where we update the 3rd party database. This stopped working after the change.

I either receive the error

> 'OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "" returned message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".'

or an error about there not being transactions. The 2nd error only occurred when I was trying to troubleshoot the issue, yesterday.

I tried adjusting the DTC settings on our server, but that just gave me the 2nd error, instead, and seemed to cause an issue with remote connections to our database...

This is all that is in the update that is breaking:

```
UPDATE [2016Instance].[DBName].dbo.EmpPers 
SET eepAddressEMail = @CurEmpEmail 
WHERE eepEEID = @CurEEID
```

Is there something else that needs to be setup for this to work? I'm considering just reworking this to be able to run from the SQL Server 2016 instance, instead, but I thought I would ask here first.

Comment: Are you sure you have write access to the database with the linked server user?

Comment: Yes, we are using the same account for the server link on the 2016 instance as the 2014 instance.  Just the 2014 one is working though.

Comment: Which SSMS are you using?

Comment: The account for the server link from 2014 to 2016 has full access on the 2016 database too.

Comment: I'm using 17.5.

Comment: Actually 17.4...  I can try to update to 17.5, to see if that affects it at all.  A job was failing though, when it tried to run the stored procedure, so I'd guess that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: So you can read, but not write? Can you insert data? Seems for me its some issues with permissions

Comment: 17.4 should be enough.

Comment: Try to read this post https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/01/12/sql-server-fix-msg-7395-level-16-state-2-unable-to-start-a-nested-transaction-for-ole-db-provider/

Comment: Try and placing the sql in a string without the linked server name.  Replacing the variables with the actual values.  Then run "Execute immediate @sql AT sql-server-link-name"  .   This will tell the database at the other end to run it locally.  If it works, then you know it's not a permissions issue.

Comment: plaidDK, I tried most of that yesterday, but didn't try the last part.  I'll try that soon.  Amir, it looks like that is Oracle syntax.

Comment: I still get the 'OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "" returned message "No transaction is active.".' error, when I include the last part from that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by moving our stored procedures to the SQL 2016 instance, setting up a link back to the SQL 2014 instance, and then changing the stored procedures on the SQL 2014 instance to just execute the new versions on the SQL 2016 instance.  This also doesn't require the DTC settings from the comments on the main question.